# Split dataframe to multiple small dataframes in R

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

I have a large dataframe I would like to split into multiple small data frames, based on the value in the `Name` column.

```
head(DATAFILE)

# Age    Site    Name    1    2    3    4    5

# 10     1      Orange   0    2    1    0    1
# 10     1      Apple    2    5    4    0    2
# 10     1      Banana   0    0    0    0    2
# 20     2      Orange   0    2    1    0    0
# 20     2      Apple    0    2    0    7    1
# 20     2      Banana   0    4    1    3    6
```

And an example file of the desired output;

```
head(Orange)

# Age    Site    Name    1    2    3    4    5

# 10     1      Orange   0    2    1    0    1
# 20     2      Orange   0    2    1    0    0
```

I have tried

```
SPLIT.DATA <- split(DATAFILE, DATAFILE$Name, drop = FALSE)
```

But this returns a large list, and I would like individual files so that I can save them as .csv files. So I would like either a better way of dividing the original file, or a way to further divide the SPLIT.DATA file.

Comment: It is better to keep it in a `list` and loop through the `SPLIT.DATA` to write to csv all at once instead of having several objects in the global envirnoment and then saving it individually.  i..e `lapply(names(SPLIT.DATA), function(nm) write.csv(SPLIT.DATA[[nm]], paste0(nm, ".csv"), row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE))`

Comment: We recommend to use `dput` to share data like this in R questions (see the R tag description) because that way it's easily reproducible by people who want to help you.

Comment: I already updated the comment.  Please check it.

Comment: Thanks @akrun, that works nicely. Is there a way to suppress the .Rdata files which are produced at the same time?

Comment: @EcologyTom  Are you using `Rstudio`?

Comment: I am not working on Rstudio, but I think the `.Rdata` files may not have any real impact.  When you close the R session without saving, these temporary files will not be saved.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will just delete the .Rdata files. Do you want to write your comments up as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is better to save the datasets directly from the `list` output of `split` itself instead of creating individual objects in the global environment.  We loop by the `names` of the 'SPLIT.DATA', and write the `list` elements to individual csv files with the same name as the names of the `list` elements by  `paste`ing the names to `.csv` in the `write.csv` call.

```
lapply(names(SPLIT.DATA), function(nm) 
   write.csv(SPLIT.DATA[[nm]], paste0(nm, ".csv"), row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE))
```

Comment: To keep the individual data.frames  from 'polluting' the global env. `list2env` is very useful.

Comment: @hvollmeier  Yes you can use `list2env`, but not recommended as most of the operations can be done within the `lsit`

Comment: @akrun Hey akrun, could be give me an idea on just when to use `lapply` or in which cases. I mean we use in almost many cases but just to make myself understand when to go for it, irrespective of what function we are using inside it.

Comment: @SowmyaS.Manian  You can use `lapply` to `list` or `vector` or `data.frame` (as data.frame is a `list` with equal length of list elements).  The difference is that it always returns a `list`.  But, `sapply` can return a `matrix` as it is by default `simplify = TRUE`.  Then, we can also use `vapply` (for fast processing) and it has additional checks as well.  The case with `rapply` is for recursive application of function and `mapply/Map` for applying functions to correspoinding elements of vector/data.frame columns/lists.

Comment: Wow `mapply/Map` would be cool!! I have read about `apply` family functions long ago mostly on what are their input types and output types and also about `tapply` and some other mix ups. But this brief helps a lot. Mostly I prefer with running more examples and checking how they work to understand each bit of it. Thanks a lot..:)